# EXCEL Files with IBM info datastage

Tags: websphere, datastage

I have some issue about "Configure the Unstructured Data stage" function in IBM info datastage.

This excel file often add columns but system need me specific data range ex.(Sheet1!A1:Z1)

So I want to know that can I specific data range like  first column to last column of Sheet1  ex.(Sheet1!A1:MAX(COLUMN)1)

Thank you and apologize about my English skill

Answer (score 0):

To set the range to the last column, you can use the 'Range Option' and 'Specify the start row'. This will automatically find the end row of the data range. If the start row has columns to column K, it will read through column K of last row. Whereas 'Specify the entire data range' you must specify both the start row and the end row of the range. You can see the description in yellow box if you put the mouse over the 'Range Option' drop down box.

If needed, there's an example you can exercise with, refer to
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.unstructureddatastage.usage.doc/topics/uds_examples.html
with range option configuration in Example 1.